# Getting an enum constant as output with an int input

Tags: java, enums

I need to write a code that outputs the day of the week, which is a constant in an enum. The input is an integer and the method converts the int to the constant. For example when the input is 0, I should get Sunday as output, and if the number is bigger than 6, then I have to use a % to get from 8 to Tuesday for example. How do I output a specific constant from enum?

The last lines are not correct, it's an idea which I don't know how to implement

```
import java.util.scanner;

public class CalendarUtil{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        enum Months{
            JANUARY, FEBRUARY, MARCH, APRIL, MAY, JUNE, JULY, AUGUST, SEPTEMBER, OCTOBER, NOVEMBER, DECEMBER;
        }
        enum Weekdays{
            SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY;
        }

        Scanner s= new Scanner();
        int day = s.nextInt();

        System.out.println(getNthWeekday(int day));

    }
    public static String getNthWeekday(int day){

        if (day≥0)%6 {
            return enum
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: java provides enmus for months nad weekdays. whyn ot use them?

Comment: With day 0 being Sunday, day 8 cannot be Tuesday, it has to be Monday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do it like this:

```
private static String getNthWeekday(int day) {

    Weekdays[] days = Weekdays.values();

    if (day >= days.length) {
        return days[day - days.length].name();
    } else {
        return days[day].name();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class CalendarUtil{

    enum Months{
        JANUARY, FEBRUARY, MARCH, APRIL, MAY, JUNE, JULY, AUGUST, SEPTEMBER, OCTOBER, NOVEMBER, DECEMBER;
    }

    enum Weekdays{
        SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){    
        Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
        int day = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println(getNthWeekday(day));
    }

    public static String getNthWeekday(int day){
     return Weekdays.values()[day%7].name();
    }
}
```

Comment: The program isn't compiling, it's giving me these errors:             CalendarUtil.java:7: error: enum types must not be local
        enum Months{
        ^
CalendarUtil.java:10: error: enum types must not be local
        enum Weekdays{
        ^
CalendarUtil.java:17: error: '.class' expected
        System.out.println(getNthWeekday(int day));
                                             ^
CalendarUtil.java:17: error: ';' expected
        System.out.println(getNthWeekday(int day));
                                                ^
4 errors

Comment: @AnnS. Since `Weekdays` is not global, it would not be known to this function. Declare it globally.

Comment: Thank you, it finally does compile! So basically I had to declare it in the class before the main method!

Answer (score 0):

Java's enums provide `ordinal()` method for each member of enum and `values()` which would allow you to fetch all members. Here is proposed solution:

```
public static Weekdays getNthWeekday(int day) {
    for (Weekdays d : Weekdays.values()) {
        if (d.ordinal() == day) {
            return d;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown day: " + day);
}
```